# How do I delete email information shown in profile

Tags: soporte

How do I delete my email information shown in profile?
And where is the user account?

Comment: What do you mean by "where is the user account"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the main site, in the status bar on the top you can see your user name to see your profile. There, there's a button "edit", there you edit your email and other profile information. Remember your email is never displayed to users, it's only for optional notifications and your Gravatar.

Comment: Thank you very much!